# Array of array of Struct swift

Tags: swift

In DataModel. swift i have a class called DataModel with this struct :

```
struct pippo {
var x : Int
var y : Int
}

struct peppe {
var z : Int
var v : Int
}

struct franco {
var a : Int
var b : Int
}
```

Now i want to create an Array of Array of struct like this :

```
var array : [[DataModel.pippo],[DataModel.peppe],[DataModel.franco]] = [[],[],[]]
```

Is there a method ?

Comment: I think you are looking for a _tuple_ instead: `var array : ([DataModel.pippo],[DataModel.peppe],[DataModel.franco]) = ([],[],[])` Am I right?

Comment: yes man you're right ahahah thank you

Comment: how can i write element in DataModel.pippo array inside array for example

Comment: Maybe you could improve your question and expalin how you will be using this array or tuple of arrays. What is the correlation between the arrays, for example why can't you have 3 separate variables instead for your arrays.

Comment: i want to populate the array inside these for make table divided in sections

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between `pippo`, `peppe` and `franco`? What do those words mean?

Comment: So if you have an array of arrays or a tuple of arrays or separate array variables is not really relevant then. Either solution is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make another struct

```
struct Name {
    var pippos = [Pippo]()
    var peppes = [Peppe]()
    var francos = [Franco]()
}
// Then array of names
var names = [Names]()
```

Comment: how can i write inside pippos array ?

Comment: let pippo = Pippo() then names.append(Name(pippos: [Pippo()]))

Answer (score 0):

```
struct pippo {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int
}

struct peppe {
    var z : Int
    var v : Int
}

struct franco {
    var a : Int
    var b : Int
}
struct Names {
    var arrayPippo = [pippo]()
    var arrayPeppe = [peppe]()
    var arrayFranco = [franco]()
}
```

//After that create a array

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var names: [Names]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for name in names {
            print(name.arrayFranco)
            print(name.arrayPeppe)
            print(name.arrayPippo)


            for franco in name.arrayFranco {
                print(franco.a)
            }
        }

    }


}
```